# How does CGContextTransalateCTM work?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to draw a box/path in drawRect in one of my view's, the path rect is:

```
CGRect pathRect = CGRectMake(self.buttonSize_ + 25, commentYOffset, rect.size.width - 80, 40);
```

and before this I have:

```
  CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0,  rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
```

I wanted this path to be drawn 100 pixels from the top, so what I did is set that commentYOffset to 100, however this doesn't do it. What am I doing wrong so that when I draw this path it starts at 100 pixels from the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGContextTranslateCTM(context,…)` applies a translation transform to context.  The translation is applied after any existing transform in the drawing context.  Those last two lines in the code you posted effectively flip the vertical on your drawing context.  Just leave them out and the path will be drawn where you want.

**Edit: adit says he needs the transforms to keep some text drawing right side up, so:** If you need to flip the vertical on your drawing context (as you're doing) then just remember that after applying these transformations zero-y is at the bottom of rect and the positive y-axis points towards the top of rect.  So to draw your path 100 pixels from the top you should make

```
commentYOffset = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 40.0 - 100.0;
```

and that 40 is because your rect is 40 points tall.  Actually it's better practice to make these named constants so you don't have to copy magic numbers all over the place going forward.  Then your code will look something like this:

```
commentYOffset = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - kPathRectHeight - kPathTopMargin;
```

Comment: removing them out will cause the text drawn to be upside down, which is not what I want

Comment: @adit OK, I have updated my answer to give a working commentYOffset without removing the transforms.